# Thrift serialization performance gain over Json with mostly String data

Tags: java, jackson, thrift

I am curious about performance gain of Thrift over Json, when the fields are 90% String.
I am currently using Jackson json library in java to serialize objects which hold mostly string value.

The object is log message containing timestamp, parameter name/value pairs, thread name, method name, class name etc... Most of the values are string.

Serialization time matters to me much, do you think it's worth to switch to Thrift to gain performance on serialization?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of other options, check out this benchmark comparision (very string heavy test)

https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization/wiki/TestPage

Comment: Is this related to http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking or why does it look so similar on the first glance?

Comment: Its not related to protobuf, its a fork of the project protobuf links to. See https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/jvm-serializers on what I have changed/added.

Comment: Oops, seems they merged my changes (did pull request). However somehow the graphs are missing for me on their page ..